# Exit status 2 when run webpack prod in jhipster

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, jhipster

I have a problem when build production with jhipster. Throw error when run webpack prod.

I am running on my dev pc. I saw VmFushion.app or wireshark.app. Does the problem have to be on my dev pc?

I use macOS. The npm version is 6.9.0 and the node version is v10.16.3. I am new to webpack. Hope to receive help.

This is error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/duc/.npm/_logs/2020-05-27T04_57_59_056Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/duc/.npm/_logs/2020-05-27T04_57_59_118Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/duc/.npm/_logs/2020-05-27T04_57_59_155Z-debug.log
```

This is debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'webpack:prod' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewebpack:prod', 'webpack:prod', 'postwebpack:prod' ]
5 info lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~prewebpack:prod: kmaclassroom@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod: kmaclassroom@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Volumes/Data/01.Data/www/kmaclassroom.com/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
9 verbose lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod: CWD: /Volumes/Data/01.Data/www/kmaclassroom.com
10 silly lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www' ]
11 silly lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod: Failed to exec webpack:prod script
13 verbose stack Error: kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid kmaclassroom@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Volumes/Data/01.Data/www/kmaclassroom.com
16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "webpack:prod"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Comment: @GaëlMarziou i run ```npm run webpack:prod```

Comment: Does dev build (npm start) work? Does it make a difference when you run a prod build using maven or gradle as documented, see https://jhipster.tech/production/#-building-a-production-package ? This is different because it uses an isolated local node environment. Also is the error complete (first block) because it seems to me that you omitted few lines before the errror.

Comment: it work with npm start. I. run ```./mvnw -Pprod clean verify``` to create .jar but throught error status 2

Comment: It could be due to something in your environment, in your path or maybe the shell you use. I'm not an OSX expert. What do you use? You might also consider using latest LTS version of node 12.x. Then try cleaning your project's node_modules and re-run npm install in project.

Comment: I updated version of node and npm. After re-run but through old error. I have spent too much time on this issue.

Comment: Yes me too. Good luck

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Have nice a day.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou It is true that I omitted an error that occurred above. ` ERROR in app/0.255becc00760e00bec8c.chunk.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: keyword «const» [./node_modules/vue2-editor/dist/vue2-editor.esm.js:876,0][app/0.255becc00760e00bec8c.chunk.js:141928,0] `.